# How to build maven war file with angular 2

Tags: angular, build, maven-3

I tried this tutorial, https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-pack-angular-8-applications-on-regular-war but it still write to me that it cant find frontend directory. This is my maven log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< org.heller.contact.app:ContactsApp >-----------------
[INFO] Building ContactsApp Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war (default-war) @ ContactsApp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [ContactsApp] in [D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\target\ContactsApp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\src/main/frontend/dist/frontend] to [D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\target\ContactsApp]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.506 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-27T12:27:25+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war (default-war) on project ContactsApp: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war failed: basedir D:\data\07_AngularContactApp\ContactsApp\src\main\frontend\dist\frontend does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

and this is my build.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.heller.contact.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>ContactsApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ContactsApp Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                        hibernate-commons-annotations
                    </artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>ContactsApp</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run buildProduction</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <!-- Add frontend folder to war package -->
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/frontend/dist/frontend</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <path>/ContactsApp</path>
                        <!-- Set update to true to avoid exist war package can not be override 
                            error -->
                        <update>true</update>
                        <!-- Because deploy this maven project using plugin in pom so use the 
                            manager-script role user. -->
                        <username>admin</username>
                        <password>admin</password>
                    </configuration>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>


    </build>
</project>
```

It should call npm run build production, but from logs it looks like it doesnt call this task. Do you have any points how to handle this, or another way to build Angular 2 project to war file? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I have

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run buildProduction</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

In plugim management section. It shoult be in plugins section of build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a maven plugin or manually do execute angular command like ng build --prod and move dist folder to resource/static folder of spring web application

by default spring mvc will server index.html folder in resource/static folder

Comment: I want to do it somehow in maven way. Should I use maven exec plugin? I thing if i simple copy frontend in dist folder to war, I will be still able to acces index.html trough http://localhost:8080/app_name/frontend/index.html.

Comment: You can use maven exec plugin but the thing is it will install node and it will download node modules again so every build will become more time-consuming. you know how much time it will take to install node modules right